# VMWare VMVisor won't install

Tags: vmware-server

I am trying to install VMWare VM Visor directly onto server hardware as an OS.
I have created a bootable USB drive using the installer, and tested booting from the USB drive on a laptop and sure enough the ESX installer pops up as expected. When trying the boot from the USB drive on the server itself, I get a message

"Remove disks or other media. Press any key to restart"

and the installer never comes up.

I don't know too many details about the Server unfortunately, so was hoping that someone could provide a high level answer of why this message might occur.

Comment: Is boot from USB enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: (sometimes, this needs "fast boot" type options disabled to allow it)

Comment: Yes, there is an option for booting via USB which is enabled. I've tried all USB ports in case only some (or one) is set up to be bootable

Comment: Can you try booting from USB with a different OS, like a Windows 8 image or similar?

Comment: Get it working?